# Set location by address or placing a marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm bulding custom form for the client. 
They want to be able to set location for Houses that they are adding trough that form.

I need two option for adding a location. 
One is by typing address into search box on Google maps and when I hit enter marker will be added to the map.

Another way is to move marker by mouse and in that case address needs to be updated by position of marker.

Only one marker ( one address ) can be on map.

Any good examples or advise?

Thanks

Comment: That´s a pretty easy and common task with google maps, the official doc´s should provide you everything you need! https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a working sample of the functionalities you have described. But, you'll be the one to incorporate the concept in your own form.

**One is by typing address into search box on Google maps and when I hit enter marker will be added to the map.**
[image]
Here's the [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vz9fspnb/9/).
Inside the `searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function(e) {}` listener, I place a function to create a marker. Whenever this listener fires due to user clicking the predicted address, a marker is placed in that same location. This doesnt work when you type specific building names. It must be an address.

**Another way is to move marker by mouse and in that case address needs to be updated by position of marker.**
[image]

Here's the [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gsc5545s/47/).
In this demo, you start by dragging the Marker anywhere on the map. When the drag event ends, '`dragend`', the Infowindow will be populated with the current address the Marker is in.

Don't forget to read more on [Javascript Map samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/).

Comment: Thank you. 

I solved it on a different way, but this answer was also useful. 

I will post my solution.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Just a simple upvote will do :)

Answer (score 0):

JS code:

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 62, lng: 15},
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    // Create a marker for each place.
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Starting location',
    position: {lat: 62, lng: 15}
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function()
    {
    document.getElementById('inputHousesLongitude').value = marker.getPosition().lat();
    document.getElementById('inputHousesLatitude').value  = marker.getPosition().lng();
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
    });

    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
    return;
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
    if (!place.geometry) {
    console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
    return;
    }
    var icon = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 10)
    };

    document.getElementById('inputHousesLongitude').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('inputHousesLatitude').value  = place.geometry.location.lng();
    document.getElementById('inputHousesAddress').value  = place.name;

    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    // Only geocodes have viewport.
    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
    }

function geocodePosition(pos)
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode
    ({
    latLng: pos
    },
    function(results, status)
    {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
    {
    document.getElementById('pac-input').value = results[0].formatted_address;
    document.getElementById('inputHousesAddress').value = results[0].formatted_address;
    }
    else
    {
    $("#mapErrorMsg").html('Cannot determine address at this location.'+status).show(100);
    }
    }
    );
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#map {
    height: 400px;
}
.controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 300px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}

#type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#target {
    width: 345px;
}
```

Comment: Mark your answer as Accepted so community knows this has been resolved :)